# Avoiding selecting same-name columns in a join

Tags: sql, join, sybase

```
TABLE_A:  columns id, colA1, colA2, ...
TABLE_B:  columns id, colB1, colB2, ...

QUERY1:   SELECT *
          FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B
          WHERE TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.id
-- This works perfectly

QUERY2:   SELECT *
          INTO #tempT
          FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B
          WHERE TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.id
-- This fails because A.id and B.id have same column name in SELECT
-- ERROR: Column names in each table must be unique.
```

One obvious way of fixing the problem with query #2 is to select all non-ID columns from TABLE_B explicitly:

```
QUERY3: SELECT TABLE_A.*, TABLE_B.colB1, TABLE_B.colB2, ...
```

The problem with that approach is 2-fold, and is really a generic problem with hard-coding exact list of columns into a SELECT query:

1. Hard-coding the columns makes the code brittle against tables that have more columns added later. Any time you add a column to TABLE_B, you will need to change, re-test, and re-release the code with the given query.
2. If there are a lot of columns in a table, the query looks awful and is hard to read due to overly-long SELECT statement

## Is there a Sybase SQL specific solution to my problem with query #2, which avoids the issue with query #3?

I am looking for a solution using Sybase SQL. NOT applicable: solutions involving using the application code to read the table structure and construct the query #3 above. Nor solutions using `eval` in-Sybase.

Comment: With standard SQL an explicit join would do that `from table_a join table_b using (id)`. That will have the `id` column (or more precisely the join columns) only once in the result. But in general, using `select *` in production code is a really bad idea.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I knew I'd some day be shamed by not knowing ANSI syntax well. Care to turn that into an answer please?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - looking into that, us "USING" construct actually supported in Sybase ASE? I know it works in Oracle but Sybase seems not to support it

Comment: I don't know, that's why I said "in standard SQL" - and just added that as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **NO**.

Long answer:

You're not going to like it, but the answer is to not use * when you are authoring a query.

Specifying which columns to select is ideal when you are writing code to use the results, so that you know which columns are part of the returned dataset.  Contrary to what you said, not specifying columns that are selected makes down-stream processes brittle, because if someone adds a column to the table, an unexpected column shows up in the resulting dataset.  If you specify each column in the select, then whenever you add a column to the table, existing reports or views work exactly as they did before.

Also, key columns are not necessarily the only ones that have ambiguity;  if you have two tables that are keyed on ID, but also have a name column (Say, a students table and a faculty table) then you will also have column ambiguity even if you exclude the ID column from the select.  However, both of those columns could be important in the result set you are looking for.

Not Sybase SQL Specific, but MSDN offers this caution about [Choosing All Columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189287%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> If a SELECT is used in an application or script that has logic dependent on the number of columns in the result set, it is better to specify all the columns in the select list instead of specifying an asterisk. If columns are later added to the table or views referenced by the SELECT statement, the application is shielded from the change if the columns were listed individually. If an asterisk (*) was specified, the new columns become a part of the result set and may affect the logic of the application or script. You should avoid using the asterisk (*), especially against catalog views, dynamic management views, and system table-valued functions. Future upgrades and releases of Microsoft SQL Server may add columns and change the order of columns to these views and functions. These changes may break applications that expect a particular order and number of columns.

Comment: Sorry, but the question wasn't "why should I not use select *", it was a specific technical problem I'm facing. While what you said has some merits in some cases, it is 100% wrong in my use case and consequently **100% unhelpful to my question**.

Comment: The answer you are requesting doesn't exist.  Even the ansi sql join using ID will not prevent duplicate column names if they exist outside of key values.  That's why this answer is THE answer.

Comment: @DVK: sometimes the correct answer is not the one you expected to get. I totally agree: Using `select *` in production code **is** code smell (e.g.: in my company this would fail a code review)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it's a correct answer to a different question ("What should I do") which wasn't one I asked. my question was explicitly the technical question of  "Can I do XYZ in SQL?", without value judgments on desirability of what I need to do. This is the worst form of X-Y "answering" possible, not knowing why the question is being asked yet stating that not doing X is the only answer.

Comment: @DVK It's the correct answer to both questions.  You said that you wanted it to be resilient to changes in the table structure, but if someone adds an additional column to Table A that has the same name as a column in Table B, it will break your script more effectively then if you specify columns based on the message you were getting.  The "value judgement" that it is a bad idea to use * in production SQL queries is only a side effect of the problems you are trying to avoid (duplicate column names, etc.).  Sorry if that offends you, but you're looking for an incorrect and impossible answer.